# How to avoid a redundant and verbose if-else-structure?

Tags: python

Is there a simpler and more efficient way to writing this code? It is a calculator on how much it costs to smoke.

There must be a way of skipping all the `if` and `elif` tags, and make it into a loop and save a few minutes of typing the code, and there may be even a "standard" in how to type code like this that I have missed.

```
how_many = int(input('How many ciggaretes do you smoke each day?\n'))

per_package = int(input('How much does your package cost?\n'))

contain = int(input('How many ciggaretes does the package contain?\n'))

cost_st = per_package / contain

choice = input('Do you want to calculate the cost per "Day (D)" / "Week (W)" / "Year (Y)" / "Decade (DE)"?\n')

if choice == 'D':
    cost_day = cost_st * how_many
    print("It will cost", cost_day ,"kr per day.")

elif choice == 'W':
    cost_week = (cost_st * how_many) * 7
    print('It will cost', cost_week,'kr per week.') 

elif choice == 'Y':
    cost_year = (cost_st * how_many) * 365
    print('It will cost' ,cost_year, 'kr per year.')

elif choice == 'DE':
    cost_DE = ((cost_st * how_many) * 365) * 10
    print('It will cost' ,cost_DE, 'kr per decade.')

else:
    print('Something went wrong! Try again please.')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and a predefined function:

```
mappings = {'D': 1, 'W': 7, 'Y': 365, 'DE': 3650}

def calculate_cigarettes(arg):
    cost = cost_st * how_many * mappings[arg]
    print('It will cost', cost, 'kr total.')
```

Comment: Thank you! Fought it would be something easy like that :)

Comment: Its 20 secounds to go

Comment: Just a follow up question if you have time. How do I call the function? And how can I search the dictionary after I have chosen if I want to calculate with D, W, Y or DE?

Comment: @Zipp0 Store it by passing the function name without the parentheses. Call it by retrieving it from the dictionary, and putting parentheses (with arguments, if any) at the end. Parentheses at the end = call the function, otherwise it is a function pointer, or whatever python's equivalent is.